# Why does the gas cost of a function change when I remove another function?

Tags: gas

I was messing around with the length of an error message to see if a message costs more or less gas when it's more or less than 32 characters long. I had the following code:

```
contract Test {
    function g() public {
        // Before
        require(true, "123456789012345678901234567890");
    }

    function b() public {
        // Before
        require(true, "12345678901234567890123456789012");
    }

    function c() public {
        // Before
        require(true, "123456789012345678901234567890123");
    }
}
```

And I noticed that the gas cost of `g()` was 183 in this configuration, but 161 when I removed function b. If I remove function c as well, it goes down to 139. How is that possible?

Comment: Are you using the optimizer during compilation?

Comment: I guess the size of the bytecode matters too. Extracting a function from a smaller bytecode will cost less than a larger bytecode.

Comment: @EnriqueAlcázarGarzás I wasn't using the optimizer, as I was trying to figure out which operations reduce gas usage.